# python-selenium, using xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Basically, I was trying to make macro program by python for buying product which is only available for only one day (it is normally sold out and only opens certain time.)

Additionally it is first time first served, hardly have a chance.

So the problem is this:

I was trying to use XPath and select elements, and then use `if` and `else` to distinguish whether I could buy it or not (based on the comparison of the products in the website which is available and not available.).

So I searched overlapped code in the page and those are found.

---

<1> the products now available looks like this

```
<ul class="_3YA58cPPsy">

<li class="_3nAZvQO51p N=a:pcs.buy">

<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="OgETmrvExa">

<span class="blind">

구매하기

</span>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

<2> the product that is not open looks like this

```
<ul class="_3YA58cPPsy">

<li class="_3nAZvQO51p N=a:pcs.mylist">

<a href="javascript:void(0)" role="button" class="_3Dy-2NaoiG" aria-pressed="false">

<span class="_3nBu7xChUl">

<span class="blind">

찜하기

</span>

</span>

<em class="_1c-2nfzJqH">

<336>

</em>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

So I was trying like those.

```py
 while True:

    xpath='//ul[@class="_3YA58cPPsy"]'

    aa=driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).get_attribute(class)

    if aa== "OgETmrvExa"
    
       print=("Yes")    

       xpath="//ul[@class='_3YA58cPPsy']"

       driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
 
       break

    else 
 
       Print=("no")
 
       driver.refresh()

       time.sleep(1)
```

Or, I was trying to use `el.text` one.

```py
   while True:

     xpath='//ul[@class="_3YA58cPPsy"]'

     el=driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)

     if  el.text="구매하기"       #<- this text is the same in <1>'s text

         el.click()
        
         break 

     else :
         driver.refresh()
```

It is not working at all.
What did I do wrong? How should I fix it?

Additionally, I will add the both <1> and <2> link, which is non-English but you would see the green button is the 'buy' button.
<1>:
https://smartstore.naver.com/coopnc/products/4871588151?NaPm=ct%3Dkl0z3145%7Cci%3Dcheckout%7Ctr%3Dppc%7Ctrx%3D%7Chk%3Df4d54ef22f2a5479043920e1957be34937fa2c1b

<2>:
https://smartstore.naver.com/hwaflora/products/5192517936

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

```py
xpath='//ul[@class="_3YA58cPPsy"]'
aa=driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).get_attribute(class)
if aa == "OgETmrvExa":
    ...
```

In this section there are two errors:

1. `class` has to be in quotes - `"class"`
2. Your XPath is finding an element based on it's class, and then you are defining a variable to the name of that class (in this case `"_3YA58cPPsy"`). aa will always be `"_3YA58cPPsy"`, so your if statement will never return true.

In this case, it might be easier to search for the div above the ul, and see how many uls there are in that div:

```py
buy = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.XqRGHcrncz")
lists = buy.find_elements_by_tag_name("ul")
if len(lists) == 2:
    buy.click()
```

In your second version:

```
xpath='//ul[@class="_3YA58cPPsy"]'
el=driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
if  el.text="구매하기" :
    ...
```

You run into a similar problem. The text you are trying to access isn't the text of the ul, but of the great-grandchild of the ul - `//ul[@class="_3YA58cPPsy"]/li/a/span`.
I think the method I referenced above is easier than finding the specific elements to extract data.

Comment: hi, thank you so much for helping me. basically u saved me. but i have another question,,, so i tried the first version but the problem was that when it is loaded as the new page, which is available to buy, it came with an error.. there was no changes and clicking the right one. i think i should click not the div but more like detailed ones which is in div class. but the problem is that it changes i believe.. for example, unlike the first link, the actual page's target button of buying changes like this xpath. -> 

//*[@id="content"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/fieldset/div[7]/ul[1]/li/a

Comment: but recently it changes into like this xpath. 
//*[@id="content"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/fieldset/div[8]/ul[1]/li/a
... so the xpath of div is different... and still css selector one, does not work(the way of clicking div is not right, i guess, it is the the button, more like having multiple buttons) i is there any suggestion for this problem? thank you so much.